# Overlapping Date Ranges - Identifying Only the Overlap

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I've seen a lot of solutions to identify records where date ranges overlap, and still other examples of merging overlapping ranges.

However I am interested in results that show the range where ONLY the overlap occurs.  In fact, I have 3 ProductIDs  (and only 3 will ever exist)  and I'm trying to find the date range for each customer of when they had ALL THREE.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 

CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
   CustomerID integer
  ,ProductID varchar(12)
  ,Eff_Dt DATE
  ,End_Dt DATE
);

-- Customer 1000: Expecting results to show 2 rows:   1/1 - 1/5   and    1/10 - 1/15
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1000,'PRODUCT_A','01-01-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1000,'PRODUCT_B','01-01-2013' ,'01-05-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1000,'PRODUCT_B','01-10-2013' ,'01-15-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (1000,'PRODUCT_C','01-01-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );

-- Customer 2000: Expecting results to show 1 row:    1/19 - 1/31
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2000,'PRODUCT_A','01-01-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2000,'PRODUCT_B','01-01-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (2000,'PRODUCT_C','01-19-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );

-- Customer 3000: Expecting results to show no rows (or nulls)
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3000,'PRODUCT_A','01-01-2013' ,'01-10-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3000,'PRODUCT_A','01-16-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3000,'PRODUCT_B','01-01-2013' ,'01-12-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3000,'PRODUCT_C','01-15-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );

-- Customer 4000: Expecting results to show 1 row:    1/15 - 1/23
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (4000,'PRODUCT_A','01-15-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (4000,'PRODUCT_B','01-01-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (4000,'PRODUCT_C','01-01-2013' ,'01-23-2013' );

-- Customer 5000: Expecting results to show 0 rows
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (5000,'PRODUCT_A','01-17-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (5000,'PRODUCT_B','01-01-2013' ,'01-10-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (5000,'PRODUCT_C','01-07-2013' ,'01-19-2013' );

-- Customer 6000: Expecting results to show 3 rows:    1/11 - 1/12   1/17 - 1/22    1/26 - 1/27
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (6000,'PRODUCT_A','01-01-2013' ,'01-04-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (6000,'PRODUCT_A','01-09-2013' ,'01-12-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (6000,'PRODUCT_A','01-17-2013' ,'01-22-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (6000,'PRODUCT_A','01-26-2013' ,'01-31-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (6000,'PRODUCT_B','01-04-2013' ,'01-28-2013' );
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (6000,'PRODUCT_C','01-11-2013' ,'01-27-2013' );

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
/* ======   EXPECTED RESULTS  =======================

CustomerID    EFF_DT        END_DT
1000          1/1/2013      1/5/2013
1000          1/10/2013     1/15/2013
2000          1/19/2013     1/31/2013
4000          1/15/2013     1/23/2013
6000          1/11/2013     1/12/2013
6000          1/17/2013     1/22/2013
6000          1/26/2013     1/27/2013

===================================================*/
```

Comment: Customer 5000 won't return any values from this dataset, as it has no date ranges where all 3 products overlap - PRODUCT_A never overlaps with PRODUCT_B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
select t.customerid, t.eff_dt, count(distinct t2.productId),
       MIN(t2.end_dt) as end_dt
from #tmp t join
     #tmp t2
     on t.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID and
        t.Eff_Dt between t2.Eff_Dt and t2.End_Dt
group by t.CustomerID, t.eff_dt
having count(distinct t2.productId) = 3
```

This is using a self-join to count the number of different products on each `eff_dt`.  You want three distinct products, so that is what the `having` clause is doing.

There are three distinct products until one of them ends.  That would be the first `end_dt` after the effective date -- which is calculated by the `min(end_dt)`.

Comment: This is a great solution.  My previous attempts tried something similar, but counting the number of distinct products during each possible date - however your solution only counts the distinct products on each EFF_DT -  brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select ab.CustomerID, 
       case when ab_Eff_Dt > c.Eff_Dt then ab_Eff_Dt else c.Eff_Dt end abc_Eff_Dt,
       case when ab_End_Dt < c.End_Dt then ab_End_Dt else c.End_Dt end abc_End_Dt
from
(select a.CustomerID, 
        case when a.Eff_Dt > b.Eff_Dt then a.Eff_Dt else b.Eff_Dt end ab_Eff_Dt,
        case when a.End_Dt < b.End_Dt then a.End_Dt else b.End_Dt end ab_End_Dt
 from #tmp a
 join #tmp b 
   on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID and a.Eff_Dt < b.End_Dt and b.Eff_Dt < a.End_Dt
 where a.ProductID = 'PRODUCT_A' and b.ProductID = 'PRODUCT_B') ab
join #tmp c 
  on ab.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and ab_Eff_Dt < c.End_Dt and c.Eff_Dt < ab_End_Dt
where c.ProductID = 'PRODUCT_C'
```

(SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1354/1))

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP
(
    CustomerID INT,
    ProductID VARCHAR(12),
    Eff_Dt DATE,
    End_Dt DATE
);
--
INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES
-- Customer 1000: Expecting results to show 2 rows: "1/1 - 1/5"; "1/10 - 1/15"
(1000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(1000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-05T00:00:00'),
(1000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-10T00:00:00', N'2013-01-15T00:00:00'),
(1000, 'PRODUCT_C', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
-- Customer 2000: Expecting results to show 1 row: "1/19 - 1/31"
(2000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(2000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(2000, 'PRODUCT_C', N'2013-01-19T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
-- Customer 3000: Expecting results to show NO rows (or nulls)
(3000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-10T00:00:00'),
(3000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-16T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(3000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-12T00:00:00'),
(3000, 'PRODUCT_C', N'2013-01-15T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
-- Customer 4000: Expecting results to show 1 row: "1/15 - 1/23"
(4000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-15T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(4000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(4000, 'PRODUCT_C', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-23T00:00:00'),
-- Customer 5000: Expecting results to show 0 rows
(5000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-17T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(5000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-10T00:00:00'),
(5000, 'PRODUCT_C', N'2013-01-07T00:00:00', N'2013-01-19T00:00:00'),
-- Customer 6000: Expecting results to show 3 rows: "1/11 - 1/12"; "1/17 - 1/22"; "1/26 - 1/27"
(6000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-01T00:00:00', N'2013-01-04T00:00:00'),
(6000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-09T00:00:00', N'2013-01-12T00:00:00'),
(6000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-17T00:00:00', N'2013-01-22T00:00:00'),
(6000, 'PRODUCT_A', N'2013-01-26T00:00:00', N'2013-01-31T00:00:00'),
(6000, 'PRODUCT_B', N'2013-01-04T00:00:00', N'2013-01-28T00:00:00'),
(6000, 'PRODUCT_C', N'2013-01-11T00:00:00', N'2013-01-27T00:00:00');
--
--
;
WITH MIN_MAX
AS (SELECT MIN(Eff_Dt) S,
           MAX(End_Dt) E
    FROM #TMP),
     ALL_DATES
AS (SELECT MIN_MAX.S DT
    FROM MIN_MAX
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, ALL_DATES.DT)
    FROM ALL_DATES
    WHERE ALL_DATES.DT < (SELECT MIN_MAX.E FROM MIN_MAX)),
     GROUPED
AS (SELECT Q.CustomerID,
           Q.ProductID,
           Q.DT,
           CASE WHEN MAX(TX.CustomerID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END YES
    FROM
    (
        SELECT *FROM ALL_DATES
            CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, ProductID FROM #TMP) AS AQ
    ) AS Q
        LEFT JOIN #TMP AS TX
            ON TX.CustomerID = Q.CustomerID
               AND TX.ProductID = Q.ProductID
               AND Q.DT
               BETWEEN TX.Eff_Dt AND TX.End_Dt
    GROUP BY Q.CustomerID,
             Q.ProductID,
             Q.DT),
     BuildFlags
AS (SELECT G.CustomerID,
           G.DT,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY G.CustomerID ORDER BY G.DT) RN,
           CASE
               WHEN WQ.tot =
               (
                   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT g2.ProductID)
                   FROM GROUPED AS g2
                   WHERE g2.CustomerID = G.CustomerID
                         AND g2.DT = G.DT
                         AND g2.YES = 1
               ) THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END FLAG
    FROM GROUPED AS G
        CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E9.ProductID) tot
        FROM #TMP AS E9
        WHERE E9.CustomerID = G.CustomerID
    ) AS WQ ),
     AddRanks
AS (SELECT *,
           BuildFlags.RN - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BuildFlags.CustomerID,
                                                           BuildFlags.FLAG
                                              ORDER BY BuildFlags.DT
                                             ) groupRank
    FROM BuildFlags)
SELECT AddRanks.CustomerID,
       MIN(AddRanks.DT) AS StartDate,
       MAX(AddRanks.DT) AS EndDate
FROM AddRanks
WHERE AddRanks.FLAG = 1
GROUP BY AddRanks.CustomerID,
         AddRanks.groupRank
ORDER BY AddRanks.CustomerID,
         MIN(AddRanks.DT)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

[You can Find the Execution at DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f00675bd924021f75dc9abe5c63b374f)