# How to avoid Overlapping of Calls in CDR's

Tags: sql

I have different fields in a table like

```
Caller_id
Called_number
Date
time 
Minutes 
Charges
```

while extracting bills for customers, there are overlapping of calls, I would appreciate if you guide me for sql script that how to avoid Overlapping calls .

eg. At one Caller_id there appears to be two calls simultaneously , same time which is not possible.

```
CallerId    Called_number   Date            Time            Minutes   Charges
5555555555  42555777777 9/12/2013   17:15:46    44     44
5555555555  5556666666  9/12/2013   17:21:28    5      9.25
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, this is possible. I've seen this many times in CDRs. Some users initiate a three-way conference call half way through a call. Also, on some systems, inbound calls can be charged to the customer. I've seen scenarios where customer is on the phone and during that call receives a inbound chargeable VM. I appreciate you're looking for some script to handle this, but I think it's important that you find the root of the issue here - otherwise, what are you going to do - ignore the second (or third or fourth) charges?

Answer (score 1):

like @SimonGoldstone said CDRs overlap can happen from many reasons:

- The data is collected by multiple servers without NTP.
- Each server uses different timezone.
- Conference call

if you do want to extract the contained calls you can use the following code:

```
create table t (
Caller_id bigint,
Called_number bigint,
call_date datetime,
duration  float,
charge   float);
insert into t
values 
(5555555555, 42555777777, '2013-12-09 17:15:46', 44, 44),
(5555555555, 5556666666, '2013-12-09 17:21:28', 5,9.25);

select t.*

from t join ( select  caller_id, called_number, call_date as start_date, 
        date_add(call_date,INTERVAL duration minute) as end_date from t) t1 on  (t.caller_id = t1.caller_id and t.call_date between t1.start_date and t1.end_date) where t.called_number != t1.called_number
```

you can also look at this post:
[Overlapping Date Ranges - Identifying Only the Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640449/overlapping-date-ranges-identifying-only-the-overlap?rq=1)